# Why do you require 100 questions in a tag before its badges are awarded?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, tag-badges

LessPopMoreFizz has a whopping [221 upvotes from 46 answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/fallout-new-vegas/topusers) in the fallout-new-vegas tag (not to mention his [129 upvotes from 18 answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/world-of-warcraft/topusers) in the world-of-warcraft users; he *is* the top user on Epic Advice after all). I have a similarly impressive [154 upvotes from 16 answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/minecraft/topusers) in the minecraft tag.

Yet, since none of these tags have 100 questions yet (minecraft has 90, fallout-new-vegas has 87, world-of-warcraft has 84), we don't get to have a badge.

What determined the 100+ total questions requirement? The [wheel of blame](http://jsfiddle.net/badp/zmV5w/36/embedded/result/) says rchern, but I don't think that's the full story. Also, can you consider somewhat lowering  this requirement?

Comment: As a side note I would like to mention that 154/16 > 129/18 > 221/46 _whistles_

Comment: I wanted to say the limit is at least related in reasoning to the reasons behind [the 200 question requirement for Generalist](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/generalist-badge-implemented/), but I'm not positive on that after reviewing it. The nature of the limits is similar but the tag badges don't necessarily need to settle to indicate what they're supposed to.

Comment: Also, [122/7](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/nethack/topusers "Which kinda proves why there's a minimum answer requirement, of course") ♪ But more to the point, note that LessPop's New Vegas score is the only one eligible for a badge as you still need at least 20 answers in total for the bronze. So, use those 10 more Minecraft questions to earn at least 4 more answers and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @Grace Aww, that's even more annoying.

Comment: What you should *really* do is bribe me to come up with Minecraft questions. I'm sure I have some given how often it's distracted me lately, but I'm lazy.

Comment: I had nothing to do with it!

Comment: @Rebecca: I keep spinning the wheel, and it keeps pointing to you.  Confess!

Comment: @Bill I spun the wheel to see whose fault it is that you kept getting my name.  Apparently, we can all just blame balpha.

Comment: On a related note: [1435/146](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/starcraft-2/topusers).  Just saying...

Comment: @tzenes You already have your badges! Shoo! :P

Comment: @Radp not the gold one... not the important one...

Comment: I guess Stack Exchange just didn't expect the amount of voting activity we have :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was part of a large scale anti-gaming implementation that protected us against abuse, for a bronze tag badge to apply we require:

1. The tag appears on 100 questions
2. You have at least **20** non-wiki answers
3. You have a total score of 100 on non-wiki questions

Additionally, unlike other badges, tag badges are revocable, if any of the pre-reqs are not met we will remove the badge.

---

**The 100 question requirement** is there to ensure the tag is widely used prior to a badge being granted. Gaming wise, this means you can not simply go to your 20 best questions and tag them "foo" to get the "foo" badge.

**The 20 non-wiki answers requirement** is there to protect us from outlier answers getting a badge without the user being a expert in the tag. Previously cletus had a `badge-o-matic` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o), all he needed to do was retag the question to get another silver badge.

---

I appreciate that it may seem a bit complex, but I think in practice this works really well. It is not going to be long before there are another 50 questions in the `fallout-new-vagas` tag and similarly the rest.

Comment: I _knew_ it! You have written code _specifically_ against Gaming! _wears conspiracy theory hat with pride_