# Should the requirement for 100 questions in a tag for tag badges be removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-badges

Inspired by [a poor soul who wanted a my-little-pony badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358705/165261).

waffles describes this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71865/165261) as an anti-gaming feature.  However, I'm not sure if that's necessarily true.  If anything, it seems to me that this would simply encourage *more* abuse, by requiring (ab)users to add the tag for which they wish to receive a badge to a larger number of questions.  On a larger site like Stack Overflow, this could probably be pretty easily concealed among all the other editing/posting traffic, especially if done over a few days by someone with full editing privileges.  On a smaller site, it'd likely be noticeable either way (and there'd be less cleanup work).

On the negative side, it prevents recognition of subject-matter experts in niche subjects, whether it's My Little Pony on SFF or a specialized library on Stack Overflow.  It also removes an incentive (other than rep, of course) for people to strive to answer more questions in such niche tags.

Should this requirement be removed?

Comment: Heh, I remember trying to hunt a [winter-bash-20something] tag badge on Meta Stack Overflow, only to realize it'd never reach the 100 questions required.

Comment: "[... provided you haven't edited the tags or previously voted to close or reopen, respectively.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/282094)".

Comment: Unlike normal badges, tag badges are revoked if one ceases to meet their criteria, so even if one does add the tag to different questions to game the badge, once those are reverted by the community, their ill-gotten badge will be revoked.

Comment: I continue to agree with waffles. It's *vastly* easier to cover up 20 retags on SO than it would be to cover up 100 of them. If a tag is only ever used for 20 questions, it's unlikely that the tag has enough currency or utility on the site to justify awarding badges for it.

Comment: @CodyGray basically means that it is close to impossible getting a tag badge for any game that isn't Minecraft on Arqade, every  fiction that isn't Harry Potter/Star Wars/LotR on SciFi and so on...

Comment: @SPArcheon [n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/386/animal-crossing-new-horizons)[o](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/273/animal-crossing-new-leaf)[p](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/215/achievements)[e](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/372/civilization-6)

Comment: @SPArcheon I don't know, I would leave it to users of smaller sites to make the decision about what they want, but this is a major issue affecting Stack Overflow, and I can speak with authority on what would be the consequences of it on that site.

Comment: @CodyGray True, and that is an historical problem StackExchange has as a whole. Most settings in the network are tuned around StackOverflow volumes, but those often don't make sense for smaller sites.

Comment: btw, about the abuse part, I think that Ryan has a point, since like he probably saw firsthand, the suggestion I got was basically to post the missing questions myself.